# How to reverse integer values from a while loop?

Tags: python, reverse, base-conversion

I am trying to write a program to convert a base 10 (decimal) number into a base 4 number. Here is the code I have come up with:

```
def decimal_to_base4(num):
    while num > 0:
        quotient = num//4
        base4 = num%4
        num = quotient
        print(base4, end="")
decimal_to_base4()
```

This code works fine, except for one problem:

For example, if my parameter value is 45, the output becomes 132. However since the base-4 value of 45 is 231, I want that output to be reversed to 231. How can I do that? I am having difficulties joining the integer outputs from the while loop, and reversing the same.

Comment: You're just printing it in the wrong order. Consider storing it the digits in a list and printing the list in reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the integer one digit at a time, then print it:

```
def decimal_to_base4(num):
    result=""
    while num > 0:
        quotient = num//4
        result+=str(num%4)
        num = quotient
    result = result[::-1]
    print(result, end="")
```

Comment: Thanks for the simply modified code. I don't understand one part of it: why have you included the 'result' accumulator? I would appreciate if you could explain the purpose of the result variable. Also, according to what I have learnt, I would initialize this to 0. Why have you initialized it to ""?

Comment: @abruzzi26 Which part don't you understand?

Comment: If you look at my code, I have included the print statement within the while loop. Why is yours outside the loop?
Secondly, what is the purpose of the 'result' variable which acts as an accumulator?

Comment: That's the point of my answer. I'm building up the result, then reversing it,  then printing it.

Comment: One more thing: why is the result variable initialized to "", and not 0?

Comment: It's initialized to `""`, which is the empty string. Each digit is converted to a string so they can be added to `result`. It's a string so that you can reverse it; you can't reverse an int.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list to store your result then print the list in reverse order

```
def decimal_to_base4(num):
    base4_ = []
    while num > 0:
        quotient = num//4
        base4 = num%4
        num = quotient
        base4_.append(str(base4))
    base4_ = "".join(base4_)
    print base4_[::-1]
decimal_to_base4(45)
```

Comment: This code is little complicated for me since I haven't reached this level yet. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to convert the number into base 4 is to first convert the number into hexadecimal (base 16) using Python's built-in facilities, then map each hex digit to two base-4 digits. Since each base-4 digit represents 2 bits, and each base-16 digit represents 4 bits, this is an exact mapping.

```
DIGIT_MAP = {"0": "00", "1": "01", "2": "02", "3": "03",
             "4": "10", "5": "11", "6": "12", "7": "13",
             "8": "20", "9": "21", "a": "22", "b": "23",
             "c": "30", "d": "31", "e": "32", "f": "33"}

def decimal_to_base4(num):
    return "".join(DIGIT_MAP[c] for c in "%x" % num).lstrip("0") or "0"
```

How it works:

- First, we convert the incoming number to hex using `"%x" % num`. We could also use `hex()`, but this adds a leading `0x` to the conversion, which we'd then have to strip off (i.e. this could also be written as `hex(num)[2:]`).
- We loop over the result, setting `c` to each character in the hex version of the number.
- For each iteration in the loop, we yield `DIGIT_MAP[c]`, which is the two base-4 digits that are equivalent to the given base-16 digit.
- We join the resulting strings with the null string, resulting in a single string with all the numbers in order.
- The result may have a leading zero since any hex digit less than `4` results in a base-4 digit-pair starting with 0. So we strip this off using `.lstrip("0")`.
- But if the number was zero to begin with, the `.lstrip()` takes off the entire digit, resulting in an empty string, `""`. The `or "0"` restores the "0" in the case of an empty string.

Comment: I would not call this the "easiest way".

Comment: Nice alternative. I am still a beginner so I would prefer short, simple codes that I can understand. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution:

```
def decimal_to_base4(num):
    if num < 4:
        return str(num)
    return decimal_to_base4(num // 4) + str(num % 4)
```

This works in the same way as the one you have, except that it solves your problem by appending the mod part to the string **after** the recursive call returns. So if you did the append in the reverse order, you are back to the same problem again

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't quite understand the purpose of the **return** function in this code. Could you please help me understand this?

Comment: @abruzzi26 There are 2 return statements which one is confusing you?

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use a recursive approach such as

```
import sys

def decimal_to_base4(num):
    if num == 0:
       return
    quotient = num//4
    base4 = num%4
    num = quotient
    decimal_to_base4(num)
    sys.stdout.write(str(base4))

decimal_to_base4(45)
```

Comment: I wanted to write a code without the help of Python's modules. Thanks for your response :)